# How to do I deploy OpenStack Icehouse using Juju?

Tags: cloud, openstack

I have been able to successfully get openstack up and running. Is there a place where i can get the icehouse openstack charms?

Answer (score 1):

The Icehouse charms are in the Juju Charm Store, in certain cases they might be in the ~openstack-charmers namespace:

This page has the information:

- https://wiki.ubuntu.com/TrustyTahr/ReleaseNotes/OpenStackCharms

If you install `charm-tools` you can use the charm command to get the source code of these charms for your current series, or you can be explicit, like so:

```
charm get cinder
charm get precise/cinder
charm get trusty/cinder
```